# Use of canvas.DrawBitmap() in android plot

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am totally new in android and
I am plotting graph on Custom View. But it is clearing previous  random plot automatically.
Is Drawbitmap()  required . Will Drawbitmap() prevent it from clearing  the canvas randomly.?

```
 @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{


  drawStuff(canvas);
}

 public void drawStuff(Canvas canvas) 
{

  PlotRealTimeGraph(canvas);
 }
```

Here this is my timer   where I am invalidating this canvas to redraw

```
 Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
       @Override
        public void run() 
        {

         postInvalidate(chanX_count1, 0, chanX_count1+7, graphheight);
        }

 },1000,40);
```

1.Here I want to ask , Shall I use drawbitmap() If yes !  then how please  suggest?
2. What if I will use this timer on Activity and Invalidate  this from there. Any help?

Comment: You should consider using a SurfaceView for your drawings, if you want the View to be frequently refreshed. I've experienced that postInvalidate is sometimes "really slow" with updating the view, as it (afaik) only posts a request that the View SHOULD be redrawn whenever the CPU has "time" for it.

Comment: Thanks  for the reply , If I will replace my  extends View to extends  Surface View will it work?

Comment: Probably not. You should read about SurfaceView. In a SurfaceView, you can access the canvas at any time - by locking it - and unlockAndPost it whenever you want. Also there are some callbacks for onSurfaceCreated/Changed/Destroyed which you might want to keep track of as well.

Comment: Ok if this is case, then How Can   I check whether it has  done postInvalidate(). Is  there any mechanism ?

Comment: Thanks I have tried  this but problem with surface View is it makes the layout opaque  with black color. I need a  transparent background.